# Retrieving ArrayList information from a class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm new to java and I've just started a project where I need to create a network from a .txt file, where each line in the file is "node1        node2", with a tabulation between nodes. I have created a node class and an edge class which accepts node names as their arguments, and now I'm writing the network class. I'm using `Arraylist` to store my nodes and interaction (edge) information, but I'm confused as to how I retrieve this information in my main program. Network class as it stands:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Network {

    public ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> edges = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String filename;

    public Network(String f) {    

        this.filename = f;

        FileReader networkinput = null;

        try {

            networkinput = new FileReader("f");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(networkinput);
            //reads the argument file in.

            String line = null;

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                edges.add(line);     // Adds each line of the file to the array
                String delimiter = "\t";
                String[] tempnodelist;  // Creates an array each loop
                tempnodelist = line.split(delimiter);
                nodes.add(tempnodelist[0]);  // Adds the first node
                nodes.add(tempnodelist[1]); // Adds second node to node array.

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Read Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands I want this code to accept the file, reach each line and place each node into the arraylist "nodes", and each line (representing an interaction) into the arraylist "edges". I'm unsure how to retrieve this information within the main program to check whether it is doing what I think it is.

Is this code doing what I expect? and how can I retrieve this ArrayList information in the main program?

Please ask any questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: *"Please any question if anything is unclear."*  Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  Or to put that another way.  What ***is*** your question?

Comment: *"Is this code doing what I expect?"* did you try? what did you get?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to try..That's the problem. How can I display ArrayLists in the main program once the file has been entered and the ArrayLists have been populated (if they actually are...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of the `Network` class to initialize everything going on in the constructor. Then access the data.

```
public class TestNetwork {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Network network = new Network("file.txt");  <-- create instance
        ArrayList<String> nodes = network.nodes;    <-- reference the data
        ArrayList<String> edges = network.edges;

        for (String s : nodes) {                    <-- traverse data
            System.out.println(s);                  <-- print data
        }

        for (String s : edges){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, another thing wrong I noticed in your constructor is this

```
networkinput = new FileReader("f");   <-- "f" I don't think is the file path.
```

You should use this

```
networkinput = new FileReader(f);

or

networkinput = new FileReader(filename);
```

Note: Consider what @erzr2 said.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Network.nodes to get the ArrayList, but this is not necessarily advisable, depending on how you use it. More advisably make the ArrayList private and create a getter method that will return the ArrayList and then you can call the method from another class. So something like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> edges = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then later have this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getNodes(){
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I needed. I wish I could have given you both a nice tick :p.